# Spam e propaganda

Tags: suporte, edição, sinalização, exclusão

Esta resposta ([Efeito usado no Tecmundo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17619/efeito-usado-no-tecmundo/30969#30969)) possuia um link supostamente para um tutorial e uma suposta fonte. Removi a a citação da fonte, já que não havia qualquer relevância. E link citado também é meramente publicitário. De nada serve a não ser promover 2 sites.

Eu removi o link da agência e sinalizei como SPAM, mas não sei se devo remover o outro link, mesmo que não sirva de nada.

Diante disso, como proceder corretamente?
Remover a publicidade grátis, sinalizar e aguardar, ou remover todos os links?

Comment: Excluí a resposta, aquele site é uma plantação de anúncios e links enganosos.

Comment: Quando for claramente com fins de promoção, deve-se remover todos os links ou deixar para remoção completa da questão?

Comment: Vote contra, sinalize e, se tiver reputação suficiente, vote pela exclusão da resposta. Se você editar e ela perder a cara de spam, outros usuários podem não perceber e deixar passar. (Depois posto uma resposta de verdade).

Comment: O rapaz nem criou uma conta FAKE, usou o mesmo nome de uruário e autor do site (LOL infinito)

Comment: @bfavaretto entendi, obrigado. É para proceder de forma correta...

Comment: Por isso eu não destruí a conta dele AINDA, pode ser que haja alguma intenção de participar direito do site.

Comment: Tomara que sim né - a esperança é a ultima que morre :)